# Converting coma separated values in multiple column to rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to create a view from a table which will convert coma separated values in multiple column to rows in Oracle.

I have done this successfully for one column. but I am not able to do it for two or three columns.

I used following script which runs successfully for one column.

```
Create VIEW MULTITESET AS 
SELECT rownum AS ID1,Tagging.COMMENTS,Tagging.category,Tagging.STATUS,
        trim(regexp_substr(Tagging.OBJ_ID, '[^,]+', 1, lines.column_value)) OBJ_ID
    FROM Tagging,
      TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
      (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual
              CONNECT BY instr(Tagging.OBJ_ID, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
      ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
    ORDER BY id, lines.column_value
```

Now I need to do the same for a second column named `OBJname` as like for column `OBJ_ID`.

So I tried something stupid as like following which won't work.

```
Create VIEW MULTITESET AS 
SELECT rownum AS ID1,Tagging.COMMENTS,Tagging.category,Tagging.STATUS,
        trim(regexp_substr(Tagging.OBJ_ID, '[^,]+', 1, lines.column_value)) OBJ_ID
    FROM Tagging,
      TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
      (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual
              CONNECT BY instr(Tagging.OBJ_ID, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
      ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
    ORDER BY id, lines.column_value ,
     trim(regexp_substr(Tagging.OBJname , '[^,]+', 1, lines.column_value)) OBJname 
    FROM Tagging,
      TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
      (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual
              CONNECT BY instr(Tagging.OBJname , ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
      ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
    ORDER BY id, lines.column_value
```

In nut shell i wanted tabel-A in the picture below to be converted to table-B. How can I do that?

[image: See attached picture]

My actual view query is:

```
SELECT rownum AS TRACKID2, LEAPFROG_TAGGING.ID, LEAPFROG_TAGGING.CREATED_DATE,
  LEAPFROG_TAGGING.CREATED_BY, LEAPFROG_TAGGING.COMMENTS,
  leapfrog_tagging.category, LEAPFROG_TAGGING.STATUS, LEAPFROG_TAGGING.OBJ_NAME,
  trim(regexp_substr(LEAPFROG_TAGGING.OBJ_ID, '[^,]+', 1, lines.column_value)) OBJ_ID
FROM LEAPFROG_TAGGING,
TABLE (CAST (MULTISET (
    SELECT LEVEL FROM dual
    CONNECT BY instr(LEAPFROG_TAGGING.OBJ_ID, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
  ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
ORDER BY id, lines.column_value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the number of comma-separated values always matches in the two columns (so exactly one name per ID), and that you're on 11gR2, you can use [recursive subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG):

```
create view multiteset as
with t (obj_id, obj_name, status, other_columns, rn, orig_obj_id, orig_obj_name) as (
  select regexp_substr(obj_id, '[^,]+', 1, 1),
    regexp_substr(obj_name, '[^,]+', 1, 1),
    status, other_columns, 1, obj_id, obj_name
  from tagging
  union all
  select regexp_substr(orig_obj_id, '[^,]+', 1, rn + 1),
    regexp_substr(orig_obj_name, '[^,]+', 1, rn + 1),
    status, other_columns, rn + 1, orig_obj_id, orig_obj_name
  from t
  where rn < regexp_count(orig_obj_id, '[^,]+')
)
select obj_id, obj_name, status, other_columns
from t;

select * from multiteset;

OBJ_ID                       OBJ_NAME STATUS OTHER_
---------------------------- -------- ------ ------
1                            a        open   value1
1                            a        closed value2
4                            hj       na     value3
2                            s        open   value1
2                            s        closed value2
5                            hj       na     value3
3                            d        open   value1
6                            hj       na     value3
4                            f        open   value1
7                            hj       na     value3

10 rows selected.
```

The column names in your question as a bit inconsistent so you'll have to adjust for your real names.

The anchor members gets the first element from each list, and keeps a copy of the original lists, and a counter to see which element we're on (starting with 1).

The recursive member then looks for the next (`rn +`) element in each list, passing the rest of the value along unchanged, apart from the counter.

The final query against the CTE then just gets the generated values, ignoring the temporary ones the CTE was keeping track of (`rn`, `orig_obj_id`, etc.)

From the new original view definition you added in comments, you might really want:

```
create view multiteset as
with t (id, created_date, created_by, comments, category, status,
  obj_name, obj_id, rn, orig_obj_name, orig_obj_id)
as (
  select id, created_date, created_by, comments, category, status,
    regexp_substr(obj_name, '[^,]+', 1, 1),
    regexp_substr(obj_id, '[^,]+', 1, 1),
    1, obj_name, obj_id
  from leapfrog_tagging
  union all
  select id, created_date, created_by, comments, category, status,
    regexp_substr(orig_obj_name, '[^,]+', 1, rn + 1),
    regexp_substr(orig_obj_id, '[^,]+', 1, rn + 1),
    rn + 1, orig_obj_name, orig_obj_id
  from t
  where rn < regexp_count(orig_obj_id, '[^,]+')
)
select id, created_date, created_by, comments, category, status,
  obj_name, obj_id
from t;
```

Also notice there is no `order by` clause; that doesn't really make sense in a view definition, and should be applied when you query the view instead:

```
select * from multiteset order by id, obj_id;
```

If you want to keep the position marker so the view resulsts can be ordered by that as well then include `rn` (or a more meaningful name!) in the final select list, e.g:

```
...
select id, rn as trackid2, created_date, created_by, comments, category, status,
  obj_name, obj_id
from t;
```

which would let you:

```
select * from multiteset order by id, trackid2;
```

Comment: thanks Alex .
i tried this . but i got following error " 02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword""

Comment: My actual view is
CREATE VIEW AS
  SELECT rownum AS TRACKID2,
  LEAPFROG_TAGGING.ID,
  LEAPFROG_TAGGING.CREATED_DATE,
  LEAPFROG_TAGGING.CREATED_BY,
  LEAPFROG_TAGGING.COMMENTS,
  leapfrog_tagging.category,
  LEAPFROG_TAGGING.STATUS,
  LEAPFROG_TAGGING.OBJ_NAME,
  trim(regexp_substr(LEAPFROG_TAGGING.OBJ_ID, '[^,]+', 1, lines.column_value)) OBJ_ID
  FROM LEAPFROG_TAGGING,
    TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
    (SELECT LEVEL
    FROM dual
      CONNECT BY instr(LEAPFROG_TAGGING.OBJ_ID, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
    ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
  ORDER BY id,
    lines.column_value;

Comment: `CREATE VIEW AS SELECT` is missing the new view's name. But please don't dump code in comments, it's really hard to read. If it's relevant, edit the question... Does that code get the missing keyword, or running the code in my answer? Which you've presumably had to modify quite a bit.

Comment: @Juliekaren - I've updated the answer with a version based on the actual view you have in your comment. If you still get an error show the whole error stack, which will give more context including line numbers.

Comment: Ohh..Sorry ,actually i trimmed the comment to fit it in.i am using this for first time so was not aware of editing it again.

Comment: Thanks  Alex, that was great help